# Linux: Unable to receive UDP packets

Tags: linux, udp, rtp, icmp

I have two machines running linux. One acts as a transmitter and the other as a receiver. I have 4 hops in between. I can send ICMP and RTP transmission from end to another. However, I am unable to receive UDP packets. I am using IPTRAF to find out if I am receiving any UDP packet on the interface. Any possible reason?

Comment: Your question is unclear, RTP is typically over UDP so if RTP works, then UDP must be working too?

Comment: Exactly I had the same concerns Ralf. However, the hops we were using some how allowed the same transmission when we switched the places of transmitter and receiver ends. Some kind of sorcery the makers of the device aren't able to stand.